# is it possible to jupyterhub on gke autopilot via helm?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, jupyterhub, autopilot

I am trying to install the jupyterhub on the gke autopilot cluster via helm using [tutorial](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kubernetes/google/step-zero-gcp.html). It gets installed but when I start the jupyterhub server from the UI(svc), getting the spawn failed error in the logs it says "block-cloud-metadata not allowed;".

is it possible to jupyterhub on gke autopilot via helm?

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer in [discourse.jupyter.org](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/experiences-with-gke-autopilot/9405/3).
I need to disable the block-cloud-metadata. It is not allowed in Autopilot.

error:

> block-cloud-metadata is privileged; not allowed in Autopilot

solution:

```
singleuser:
  cloudMetadata:
    blockWithIptables: false
```